# Problems handling sc_logic values in SystemC

Tags: c++, c, systemc

I'm writing an application in order to simulate a hardware system using SystemC libraries.
My problem is handling the `sc_logic` type.
Consider a simple module

```
SC_MODULE(MyModule) {
   sc_in_clk clk;
   sc_out<sc_logic> outsig;
   void main_process();
   SC_CTOR(MyModule) {
      SC_METHOD(main_process);
      sensitive << clk;
   }
};
```

Consider the implementation of the process:

```
void MyModule::main_process() {
   this->outsig.write(SC_LOGIC_1);
}
```

OK.
Problem: `outsig` is always `'0'` and never changes its value.
I write many signals in my simulation but this problem occurs only with `sc_logic` values in `sc_out` ports.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: I don't remember anything special about sc_logic. I think default value is 0, so writing SC_LOGIC_1 should trigger the output port and attached to it signal. It definitely works when I write this test case using GBL library (www.gbresearch.com/gbl). Maybe you need to check that clk is actually coming and main_process() is being called. Set a debug breakpoint in main_process.

Answer (score 0):

Put `sensitive << clk` **before** `SC_METHOD` in the constructor.